# Алгоритм вычленения и сортировки данных

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, машинное-обучение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть большой объем данных по которым впоследствии строятся графики, условно вид следующий:

При построении по этим данным получается каша из линий, на которых еле-еле можно различить отдельные  прямые или синусоиды.

Необходимо вычленить данные и построить графики "Один График на рисунке". Мои идеи это:

- брать начальные значени и следующие выбирать путем нахождения меньшей дельты (может есть какое-либо название у такого алгоритма)
- Либо воспользоваться одним из методов классификации из scikit-learn

Пните, пожалуйста, в нужном направлении.

Comment: Постановка вопроса очень странная. Что значит "вычленить данные"? Это всё данные от одной системы? Если да, то зачем их вычленять, тогда график будет не объективен, если нет, то для чего они были помещены в одно место?

Comment: @ПавелКовтун данные были даны были в таком виде, сам не пойму как так измеряли, но все сохранили в один файл. Да, все данные от одной системы, но как мне объяснил научрук - "Это должны были получиться большое количество графиков, но каким-то образом все попало в один файл"

Comment: Ну так а что вы в таком случае хотите, из одного потока данных невозможно вычленить те, которые относятся к конкретному графику без какой-либо дополнительной информации, наименьшая дельта вам ничего не даст, выбранные в результате точки могут относиться к разным графикам. Если что-то и получится материализовать графически, то это точно не будет объективный анализ данных.

Comment: Покажите лучше не условные, а реальные данные. Если нельзя показывать все по каким-то соображениям, то хотя бы данные для нескольких последовательных отсчётов по оси `X`. Думаю, тут можно что-то придумать, но без реальных данных тяжеловато. Так то задачка даже интересная.

Comment: Переменная X - целочисленная? Для каждого X, число точек совпадает? Т.е. для каждого графика есть все точки по X?   Попробуйте минимизировать сумму квадратов вторых производных в каждой точке.

Comment: @CrazyElf вот кусочек

Comment: @Chorkov добавил кусочек данных - не целые

Comment: Ну не в виде картинки же ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас линии настолько хорошо разделимы, как это выглядит на картинке с частью данных, и в них нет разрывов (значение `y` по каждому из графиков есть для каждого значения `x`), то ваши данные можно просто отсортировать и перенумеровать с использованием библиотеки `Pandas`. Пример с генерацией подобных данных (поскольку вы не предоставили свои данные в воспроизводимом виде):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Генерация искусственных данных
n = 20
k = 10
x = np.arange(0, n, 1/k).astype(np.int32)
y = np.array(list(range(k))*n) * 10 + np.random.rand(n*k)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

# Простое рисование
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x='x', y='y', data=df, estimator=None)

# Нумеруем графики
df = df.sort_values(['x','y'])
df['num'] = df.groupby(['x']).cumcount()

# Отрисовка отдельными линиями
plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(x='x', y='y', hue='num', data=df)
```

График данных "как есть":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График данных после сортировки и разметки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так видимо не получится, потому что он в самой формулировке писал 
"При построении по этим данным получается каша из линий, на которых еле-еле можно различить отдельные прямые или синусоиды."

Comment: @Павел А пусть попробует и ответит. У меня на исходном графике тоже мешанина в общем-то

Comment: @CrazyElf поменял картинку, в принципе, не получилось. Могу скинуть часть данных... Сам пока так и не смог осилить, какжется не хватает знаний

Comment: @Nyūron Ну скиньте уже куда-то данные, да. Судя по картинке, у вас по каким-то данным есть промежуточные точки, а по каким-то нет. Это сложнее, конечно, но тоже решаемо, хотя придётся подумать.

Comment: @CrazyElf [тестовые данные](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZFPxPUmfOQcfHUM54sKok5NSYu0GPDc/view?usp=share_link)